# What is the best free hosting provider for my site?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I have a small "hobby" site that generates almost no income for me (but still is fun to run, and that's why I keep it around). The site get's about 75 hits a day, though I could easily see that increasing to 200 or more in the future. I want to move it to a free hosting provider. The hosting provider should support the latest versions of php and mysql, should be able to run wordpress installations, and should have pdo and sendmail enabled. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article that has a list of free hosts: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-7-easy-and-free-web-hosting-services/

Answer (score 3):

Amazon AWS have a free tier (http://aws.amazon.com/free/).

Otherwise Wordpress themselves can do hosting on a custom domain.

Comment: @Metalshark I would prefer to use a host that I can use for free infinitely, not something that I can use for free _for a year_ (in the case of AWS). And I would use wordpress.com, accept that my site has a forum and that I want to be able to install whatever plugins/themes/software I want, which is something I can't do with wordpress.com

Comment: @Christofian AFAIK only Byet http://byethost.com/index.php/free-hosting offer truly free VPS that is sensible for your needs. Although I cannot recommend it as they can take it away again at any time.

Comment: I don't think wordpress does free custom domain hosting. Doesn't it have to be something like YOURSITE.wordpress.com

If you want it to be a custom url, you have to pay wordpress like $15 or something.
https://en.wordpress.com/signup/

Comment: @Metalshark what do you mean by "they can take it away _again_ at any time". Do you mean that they might suddenly pull the plug on their free hosting service. Can you give me more info?

Comment: @Melanie I wasn't planning on wordpress.com anyway, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: Just adding info for any other users that have a similar question and happen upon this one. :)

Comment: @Christofian wish I could give you specifics, but it's just buried as a T&C and never mentioned again.

Comment: @Melanie sorry, I'm new here :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that most free hosts that allow you the comprehensive control you are looking for (stuff that isn't just pre-installed soft for your use: blogger.com, wordpress.com, etc) will likely require you to show some sort of ad or backlink on your site. If this is something you are open to, I may be able to dig something up for you.

There is also this site which doesn't require an ad or anything and it says they are free. I cannot tell you, however, how legit this is: http://www.freehosting.com/client/cart.php

Alternatively, if you're on a connection with a static ip and have another machine lying around, it would be a cinch to throw some flavor of linux on there and install whatever you need to keep a hobby site up.

Comment: I'm open to a backlink, but not an add. Also, I would like to be able to add the backlink myself, instead of it being inserted automatically at the footer, if possible.

Comment: Post edited, let me know if it meets your needs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this http://www.freewebhostingarea.com/ .I used this before and i never faced any problems.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Nearly Free Speach.
https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/

It's not free.. but it's close.

Answer (score -1):

000webhost is not bad but dont get lured into their other company,Hosting 24.It has a bad reputation. And there s no ads at all.I was even impressed for a free service.

Comment: `000webhost` shuts your website down periodically to check for "potentially unwanted content" (for them), not recommended.

Comment: i didnt know that though. oops!