# Where can i find free webhosting with pdo mysql and curl enabled?

Tags: mysql, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best free hosting provider for my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/what-is-the-best-free-hosting-provider-for-my-site)

I am looking for a free web host for a existing .com domain with **pdo mysql and curl** enabled

Comment: Note: It's not obvious from the title but the proposed duplicate also required PDO.

Comment: i need also curl to be enabled so where is the duplicate content?