# What's the most reliable FREE web hosting for WordPress blogging?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'd like to hear the opinion of those who have been using such a service for at least half year or more.

I have my own registered .com.ar domain. It would be great if it is ad-free also.

Thanks in advance for your sharing your experience.

Comment: hello? why you close this? I'm asking for names of free webhosting providers, because I need to know which are the most used, and the most reliable. The post you linked does not help me at all.

Comment: We've got a ton of question asking people to recommend hosting for people, so we closed all the questions about hosting recommendations accept for one (the post linked). If the linked question doesn't answer your question, then try wordpress.com or this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/what-is-the-best-free-hosting-provider-for-my-site